# How can I use shared view model in jetpack compose for one textfield?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I have one textfield for user phone number, and I want to use this phone number for both register users to `Firestore` and using it for mobile authentication, so I have two ViewModel and I want to use `ShareViewModel` for this number textfield, is it possible to use it in android jetpack compose?

`AuthViewModel`:

```
    @HiltViewModel
    class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    
        val auth: FirebaseAuth
    
        ) : ViewModel() {
    
  .....
    
    
    
        }
```

`RegisterViewModel` :

```
   @HiltViewModel
    class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(
        val db: FirebaseFirestore,
        val auth: FirebaseAuth,
   
    
    ) : ViewModel() {
    
 
      ......
        }
```

`RegisterScreen` :

```kotlin
    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun RegisterScreen(
    
        navController: NavController,
        model: RegisterViewModel
    
    ) {
    
       val phoneNumberState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    
        OutlinedTextField(
                value = phoneNumberState.value,
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = white,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                    focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                    unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                    cursorColor = custom,
                    textColor = custom,
    
                    ),
                onValueChange = { phoneNumberState.value = it },
                label = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                }),
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
                singleLine = true,
                
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
    
            )
    
             Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(205.dp)
                        .height(35.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        focus.clearFocus(force = true)
                        model.onSignUp(
                            phoneNumberState.value,
                     
                        )
                        navController.navigate("otp")
    
                    },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        backgroundColor = custom
                    ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(30)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Next",
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 11.sp,
                            color = white,
    
                 ))
              }}
```

**PhoneVerifyScreen:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun PhoneVerifyScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    modelAuthentication: AuthenticationViewModel,
    onClick: (mobileNum: String, otp: String) -> Unit
) {

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val phoneNumberOTP = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        println("found activity? ${context.findActivity()}")
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        modelAuthentication.setActivity(activity)
    }


    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() } 
            ) {keyboardController?.hide()}
        ,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {


        OutlinedTextField(
            value = phoneNumberOTP.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                cursorColor = custom,
                textColor = custom,

                ),
            onValueChange = { phoneNumberOTP.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Verify code") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Verify code") },
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),

        )


        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(285.dp)
                    .height(55.dp),
                onClick = {

                    modelAuthentication.otpVerification(phoneNumberOTP.value)

                    navController.navigate("profileScreen")


                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = custom2
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(60),
           
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        color = white,


             ))
            }}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a `viewModel` in your `MainActivity`, and this viewModel will be the shared viewModel, you can pass it to other screens or just pass function that set phone number to that sharedViewModel

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val sharedViewModel by viewModels<SharedViewModel>
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            App(sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for ur answer, but how I will use for textfield both viewmodel

Comment: you can have a function in your shared view model that will receive the phone number and save it in the shared view model, and another function of a variable that will return the saved phone number, use the first one in RegisterScreen to save the phone number and use the second one in the screen that uses AuthViewModel to get the saved phone number

Comment: Is it possible to update answer for question detail,  I am not understanding it

Comment: I need you to update your code, I need to know in which screen you are using AuthViewModel, where you will use that phone number ?

Comment: sorry I forget update question now I update it :)